# Does Python have andmap / ormap?

Tags: python

I am still a beginner at coding, especially with python. In one of my freshman classes, we were introduced to racket, a functional programming language very similar to scheme. In this class we learned about the functions `andmap` and `ormap`.

Is there a built in `andmap` and `ormap` in Python?

Comment: @L3viathan In racket andmap and ormap applied a function that returned true or false on each interable then andmap would return true only if all the iterables returned true when applied to the input function. Ormap returned true when any of the iterables in the list returned true to the applied function. I looked up all and any, I think these functions just check if an/all elements are true. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Have you tried it? Can you give me an example of where `any` and `all` don't behave as you'd expect from `andmap` and `ormap`?

Comment: @L3viathan Ok just tested it. `any` and `all` are not what I am looking for. I want to map a function over my iterable. That function I am mapping over the iterable returns true or false. I want to see if all the items in the iterable return true (andmap) or I want to see if any of the items in the iterable return true (ormap).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python has the `map` function that applies a function to a sequence plus `all` and `any` that perform the `and` and `or` functions. These short-circuit as soon as their condition is violated.

```
any(map(somefunction, sequence))
all(map(somefunction, sequence))
```

Python also lets you iterate and apply functions to a sequence directly in the language

```
any(somefunction(x) for x in sequence)
all(somefunction(x) for x in sequence)
```

Comment: Ah I knew python had map but I figured some convenient function was built into python that would add the extra step of checking whether the result of the map passed an `all` or `any` test. (Although I didn't know `all` and `any` existed!)